# Priority inheritance vs priority ceiling

Tags: scheduler, scheduling, race-condition, rtos

Both [priority inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_inheritance) and [priority ceiling protocols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_ceiling_protocol) are used to minimise the consequences of a race condition. They both dynamically change the priority of tasks that hold a resource, needed for execution of a higher-priority task, which "unstucks" it.

What I cannot find in any literature is:

1. How are their algorithms of changing a task priority different?
2. In what situations one is preferable to another?